# uploading original size image to server

Tags: android, image

I am uploading an image to server but the problem is when i am scaling the image and uploading it to server it is working fine but the image is too small...how can i get the original size image on server side...without scaling i am getting out of memory exception.... Is there any way using which i can upload my image to server or i can convert the scaled image back to previous one. i have already used large heap in manifest. please help me out...

```
imageUpload=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path);
           stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          imageUpload1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( imageUpload, 100, 50, true);
           imageUpload1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream); //compress to which format you want.
           /*ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
           imageView.setImageResource(imageupload1);*/

           byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
//          image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);




          //  albumThumbnail = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
             albumThumbnail = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);

          //add this line
            imageUpload1.recycle();
            imageUpload1= null;

          }
    }

    private void uplaodImageServer() 
    {
        getDateAndTime();
        albumName=albumTitle.getText().toString();

        Log.e("albumname",albumName);
        Log.e("filePath",file_path);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("albumtitle",albumName));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("albumthumbnail", albumThumbnail));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dateCreated",dateCreated));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filePath",file_path));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imagename",uploadImageName));
         // FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);


          try
          {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost=new HttpPost("http://ur ip address/freeJeetoAndroid/CreateAlbum.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: why do you not send it as a file? use FileOutputStream?

Comment: well, you send the image with a simple outputStream. no scaling or something, you just send the data and that's it. there are thousands of how-to's on the internet. and your server will get the file in it's original format, you can also transfer audio or video files this way. it is very simple

Comment: @ZerO: ohk let me try then...

Comment: @ZerO: i will have to send my image as byte array hence i will have problem converting it back in php

Comment: and this does not work in php?

Comment: @ZerO: i tried it in my previous project it created a lot of problem..so i used string

Comment: you used string for exactly what?

Comment: @ZerO: for sending image as string (base64)

Comment: @ZerO: yes well i have solved the problem u can check it if u like

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have found the solution to my above question. Hope it will help someone...

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

           Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
           String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

           Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
             filePathColumn, null, null, null);
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           columnindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
           file_path = cursor.getString(columnindex);
           // Log.e("Attachment Path:", attachmentFile);
          // tv_attach.setText(file_path);
           Log.e("file_path",file_path);
           URI = Uri.parse("file://" + file_path);

           //Retrieve filename and extension

           Filename imageFileName = new Filename(file_path, '/', '.');
           extension=imageFileName.extension();
           fileName=imageFileName.filename();
           System.out.println("Extension = " + imageFileName.extension());
           System.out.println("Filename = " + imageFileName.filename());
           //System.out.println("Path = " + imageFileName.path());
           cursor.close();

           uploadImageName=fileName+"."+extension;
           imagename.setText(uploadImageName);


           BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//        by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//        you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path, options);

            int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
            int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

//        max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

            float maxHeight = 816.0f;
            float maxWidth = 612.0f;
            float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
            float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

//        width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

            if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
                if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {               imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);               actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;             } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                    imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                    actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                    actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
                } else {
                    actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                    actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

                }
            }

//        setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//        inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//        this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inInputShareable = true;
            options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

            try {
//            load the bitmap from its path
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path, options);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();

            }
            try {
                scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }

            float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
            float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
            float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
            float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

            Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
            scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
            canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//        check the rotation of the image and display it properly
            ExifInterface exif;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(file_path);

                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                if (orientation == 6) {
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                    Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                } else if (orientation == 3) {
                    matrix.postRotate(180);
                    Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                } else if (orientation == 8) {
                    matrix.postRotate(270);
                    Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                }
                scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                        scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                        true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//            write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
                scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);




//         imageUpload=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path);

            //imageUpload1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( imageUpload, 256, 256, true);
//           imageUpload.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream); //compress to which format you want.
           /*ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
           imageView.setImageResource(imageupload1);*/

           byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
//          image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);




          //  albumThumbnail = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
             albumThumbnail = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);

          //add this line
//          imageUpload.recycle();
//          imageUpload= null;

          }
    }

          public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
                final int height = options.outHeight;
                final int width = options.outWidth;
                int inSampleSize = 1;

                if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
                    final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height/ (float) reqHeight);
                    final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
                    inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;      }       final float totalPixels = width * height;       final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;       while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
                    inSampleSize++;
                }

                return inSampleSize;
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to your question - it's subsampling the image so you aren't keeping the original dimensions, and it doesn't show the image being uploaded.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey: i jus wanted my image to be uploaded on sever and to be viewed the way it is...n the code for uploading is the same